# It seems my class is being given both my error and success class when it should only be given the success class

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I've got a form that im trying to validate, I have put `div`'s around my `input` box and text box that needs to be required, but when I enter something in the box and submit, it wont submit because there are other things not selected, but it gives my `div` the error and success class when it should only be success...

jquery validate code:

```
$("#frm_enter").validate({
    ignore: 'hidden:not(input[name=\'terms,privacy,iam18\'])',
    onkeyup: false,
    errorElement: "div",
    rules: {
        code:{required: true,},
        terms:{required: true,},
        privacy:{required: true},
        iam18:{required: true}
    },
    messages: {
        code:{required: "Code is required"},
        terms:{required: "Please accept terms and conditions"},
        privacy:{required: "Please accept privacy notice"},
        iam18:{required: "Please verify you are 18 or older"}
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.appendTo( '#v_' + element.attr('id') + '.frmvalidate' );
          $('#v_' + element.attr('id') + '.frmvalidate').parent().addClass("error1");
         console.log("is this working");
    },
    success: function(label) {
        $("#submit").prop('disabled', false);
        console.log(label);
         $(label).parent().parent().addClass("valid1")
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class = "input_validate">                                  
<div class="board_question">
Code :                                  
</div>                          
<div class="board_input">                               
<input type="text" maxlength="11" id="code" name="code" />                          
</div>                              
<p id="v_code" class="frmvalidate"></p>                             
</div>
```

I was hoping it would give my `input_validate` class a class of `valid1` but it gives me both `valid1` and `error1`

Answer (score 0):

You're using the options of this plugin incorrectly.  You should not be using `errorPlacement` and `success` for adding/removing any classes.  These two functions do not fire when you expect them to.  `errorPlacement` only fires to place the error within the layout, then the plugin toggles visibility of the label during validation.  `success` fires when the element is completely valid but its intended purpose is to leverage the validation message label when the element is valid rather than simply hiding it.

In order to automatically add/remove the valid/invalid classes during validation, you should only be using the `highlight` and `unhighlight` functions for this.

[I suggest you read the full documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/).